# Sample application/tutorial for a layered application in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, architecture

I'm developing an enterprise-like application that fetches data from a remote server. I have a vague understanding of how to construct a layered application with these two layers at present:

1> View Controllers & NIBs: To display my UI

2> Data Provider class (singleton): That the view controllers can request data from and which in turn fetches its data from the remote server

I would like to see a sample application/tutorial with a real life scenario that is easy to follow and that illustrates how such applications should be built.

I do not have a background in web development and I understand there is a pretty standard way the classes that comprise these layers are created, best practices etc. Can someone point me to any resources available out there for iOS that demonstrate these issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats a hefty goal mate, one of the best examples of web services is :
[Ray Wenderlichs web services](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service)

Its a very very good tutorial and the one before it shows how to create a web service yourself
The GUI can be anything you want but I recommend keeping the GUI fairly basic to begin with, get the web connectivity concepts down first, they can be tricky.

You dont really need much web development skills, just enough to make an intermediary php file
These Tutorials : [From TheNewBoston](http://www.thenewboston.com/?cat=39&pOpen=tutorial) are amazing for learning basic php in a few hours, enough to post from a form to a database and retrieve.
Cant find any good iPhone > php > sql databases at the mo but theres a few out there

post up your progression and people will be glad to help

Good Luck